# How to output raw brace `{}` in react?

Tags: reactjs

html:

```
<p>{...}</p>
```

I want to get the output like this:

```
{...}
```

How to do this? Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<p>{"{...}"}</p>` should work.